# Error using gcc command to compile ARMv8 code on RaspberryPi [Undefined (.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `printf']

Tags: linux, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm64, armv8

I'm trying to compile this code for a double dabble algorithm binary to bcd but keep getting errors when trying to compile to a bin file.

(This is on a raspberry pi)

```
/* binary2bcd2.s */
.global main
.text

binary2bcd2:
      sub    sp,sp, #32
      str    w0, [sp, 12]
      str    wzr, [sp, 28]
      b      .L2
.L3:
      ldr    w0, [sp, 12]
      sub    w0, w0, #1
      ldr    w1, [sp, 12]
      and    w0, w1, w0
      str    w0, [sp, 28]
.L2:
      ldr    w0, [sp, 12]
      cmp    w0, 0
      bgt    .L3
      ldr    w0, [sp, 28]
      add    sp, sp, 32
      ret
.LC0:
      .string "%d"
.LC1:
      .string "The amount of bits is  %d\n"

main:
      stp    x29, x30, [sp, -32]
      mov    x29, sp
      add    x0, sp, 28
      mov    x1, x0
      adrp   x0, .LC0
      add    x0, x0, :lo12:.LC0
      bl     __isoc99_scanf
      ldr    w0, [sp, 28]
      bl     binary2bcd2
      mov    w1, w0
      adrp   x0, .LC1
      add    x0, x0, :lo12:.LC1
      bl     printf
      mov    w0, 0
      ldp x29, x30, [sp], 32
```

This is my second assembly code so I'm still a bit baffled by compile commands.

When I try and compile I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ as -o binary2bcd2.o binary2bcd2.s
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ld -o binary2bcd2.bin binary2bcd2.o
ld: binary2bcd2.o: in function `main':
(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `__isoc99_scanf'
ld: (.text+0x8c): undefined reference to `printf'
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I know it's somewhat related to a library issue. So I googled it and found this command on a question from here:
gcc binary2bcd2.o -o  binary2bcd2

(The question title was **Linking an assembler program: error "undefined reference to printf"**)

I tried it and got this error instead:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ gcc binary2bcd2.o -o  binary2bcd2
/usr/bin/ld: binary2bcd2.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'; /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

I  don't really know what gcc does so i could be using the wrong thing. if there are resources that explain what each command does that would be very helpful to me :) Every assembly example I find online skips the header and compiler parts of writing assembly code and just talks about ADD and STR and such.

Comment: Using bare `ld` by itself doesn't link libc.  If you have your own `_start` that uses libc functions, you want `gcc -nostartfiles` to link normally except for CRT start files.  (dynamic executable, with `-lc -lgcc`, and `-pie` all implied.  Well maybe not `-pie`, depends on your distro's config of GCC)  Use `gcc -v ...` to see exactly what it's doing.  Your code doesn't include a `_start` so IDK if it's actually a [mcve] of your error with GCC.

Comment: Also, don't forget to have your `main` end with a `ret`, or your `_start` end with a call to `exit` (not a raw syscall or `_exit`; you want libc cleanup functions to run if you've been using stdio).  (`_start` can't `ret`, it's not a function.)

Comment: I used gcc -v but I don't quite know what to make of all this text. https://textdoc.co/R8xENQrdJi2hlLC1

Comment: Try `gcc -o binary2bcd2 binary2bcd2.s`.  Your code does not contain a `_start` symbol, so this is very confusing to me.

Comment: I think I somehow deleted it. Thanks for the reminder. @fuz